# Accessing a Mobiles Camera From Its Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I was wanting to make a webpage that streams my phone's camera to the webpage so that I could add a filter on top while it records. Sort of like Snapchat but on the browser instead of an app.

So far, all I can find is the option to record a video and then have the video display afterwards on the browser. I am however looking for a live stream option.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 getUserMedia, heres a tutorial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia